# Django: вывод текста из моделей

Tags: python, html, django

В модели указывается текст в различных строчках. При выводе в html он вывод текст слитно, не разделяя на строки. Как исправить?

Указываю в модели:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почитать учебник по HTML и узнать, как в в нём принципе разделяются строки. Более конкретно, можно использовать CSS-стиль `white-space: pre-wrap` или каким-то образом заменить символ переноса строки на `<br/>` перед выводом (но тогда нужно будет повозиться с экранированием)

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо)